# Node.js on raspberry-pi cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, mpi, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing

I built a cluster of 4 nodes with Raspberry following this tutorial: http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/pi_supercomputer_southampton.htm

Now I want to run a Node.js (webserver) application using this cluster with MPI or otherwise

How is the best way to do this? More transparently?

I've used another computer as a load balancer, directing the request to each node, but it did not seem the right way to use a custer, as a single machine.

I was watching the PM2, which has self scale, but I believe it only works for single machine.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to run node.js in MPI, since node.js does not use the MPI api.

Comment: So i have the wrong idea about cluster for node.js. Use loadbalance is the best way for that?